# How to do silent install for any software in MAC osx?

Tags: macos, installation

I want to install mysql database software. 
I don't want to install as by giving procedure, i want to install in a silent manner.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this :

```
$ hdiutil attach <PackageName>.dmg
$ sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/<PackageName>/<PackageName>.mpkg -target /
$ hdiutil detach /Volumes/<PackageName>
```

Here is the official [hdiutil documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html).